# Proptypes for object required or null?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

How do you declare proptypes for object or null? I tried this but don't work:

```
page: PropTypes.oneOf([
    PropTypes.shape({
      elements: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      isFailed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      isRefreshing: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      isSuccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
    PropTypes.oneOf([null]).isRequired,
  ]).isRequired,
```

or possibly like this?

```
page: PropTypes.oneOfType([null, 
        PropTypes.shape({
          elements: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
          isFailed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
          isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
          isRefreshing: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
          isSuccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        }).isRequired]).isRequired
```

Answer (score -1):

this doesn't feel correct though but it works:

```
PageItem.defaultProps = {
  page: null
}
PageItem.propTypes = {
  page: PropTypes.shape({
    elements: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    isFailed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isRefreshing: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    isSuccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }),
}
```

i've just removed the isRequired on page shape

Comment: the null is for when the data is fetching

Comment: Will it throw a warning if page is `undefined`?